# UserControl property "relay" between internal controls and viewmodel; does not feel/work right

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am doing a simple user control. For example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FileSelectionControl">
  <StackPanel>
    <Label>File path:</Label>
    <TextBox
      Text="{Binding Path=SelectedFile,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType=l:FileSelectionControl},
              Mode=TwoWay,
              Converter={StaticResource fileInfoToStringConverter},
              UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
              ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

SelectedFile is a property (DependencyProperty) exposed by my UserControl that holds a FileInfo to represent the selected/specified file. It is meant to be bound to a viewmodel's property.

Binding setting, slighty more general:

[image: Illustration]

This kind of works, although not properly and it does not feel right. SelectedFile property acts like a relay between inner controls and viewmodel. It would be more straightforward for the textbox to be bound to the same source SelectedFile was set to...

For example, one drawback I am experiencing is with input validation. Viewmodel implements IDataErrorInfo. If I enable validation for SelectedFile, UserControl gets highlighted. But I need validation (notification) for the inner textbox.

So what would be a good way to deal with this?

**Added 2012-03-30** (user control viewmodel instead of custom properties):

I thought of the user control more like a custom control... What if I implemented a CustomControl with a ControlTemplate and TemplateBindings to CustomControl's custom properties (much like in my initial approach)? (D)Ps on the control are the way to go, aren't they? I don't feel an associated viewmodel would make an acceptable "interface" to a CustomControl.

Comment: can you use a `DataTemplate` with your ViewModel (instead of a `UserControl`)?

Answer (score 2):

Usually if a `UserControl` is complex enough to require it's own `ViewModel`, all my properties go in the `ViewModel`, and the `UserControl` has no Dependency Properties, except for perhaps a `ViewModel` property.

For example, I might use it like this and have the `UserControl` assume it's `DataContext` is of type `FileSelectionViewModel`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FileSelectionViewModel}">
    <my:FileSelectionUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

Or I might do this and have my `UserControl` use a `RelativeSource` binding to reference the `ViewModel` property on itself:

```
<my:FileSelectionUserControl FileSelectionViewModel="{Binding FileSelectionVM}" />
```

Usually the only time I make dependency properties for a `UserControl` is if the property relates to the View only, and not the data, such as an `IsSomeFeatureVisible` property.

Comment: Thanks so far. I changed the user control to have its own viewmodel + datatemplate. It works and prevents some duplicated code/data structure in a parent viewmodel, when the control is used more than once. On the other hand, simplicity of my parent viewmodel code suffers, because it has to explicitely monitor changes to the controls viewmodel and also because there are dependencies between two parallel instances of the user control.